# Error in simple mode finding algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I'm working through a few chapters on algorithms from the Discrete Math text by Rosen.

In the solutions manual there is an algorithm (specified in pseudocode) for finding the mode within a list of non-decreasing integers.

Here is the algorithm:

```
procedure find a mode(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n : non-decreasing integers)
modecount = 0
i = 1
while i <= n 
    value = a_i
    count = 1
    while i <= n and a_i == value
        count = count + 1
        i = i + 1
    if count > modcount then
        modecount = count
        mode = value
return mode
```

Now, I immediately see a problem with this algorithm. For instance, take the list $<1,2,2,2,4,4,4>$ we see that the following steps are followed, counting the element $1$ twice when it only appears in our list once.

Steps below begin upon first entry of the body of the while loop:

Step 1. Assign $a_1=1$ to $value$.

Step 2. Assign $1$ to $count$

Step 3. Check that $i=1 \leq 7$ and that $a_1=1$ equals $1=value$.

Step 4. Increase the value of $count$ by $1$ so that $count := 2$.

But we only have $1$ appearing once in our list and we have counted it twice.

Is my interpretation of this algorithm incorrect? To me $count$ should first be set to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right.  The pseudocode is clumsy, poorly constructed, and confusing.  At the end of the outer loop, `modecount` holds the number of times that `value` appears in the array, plus one.  That's weird and not what you'd expect from the variable name: from the variable name, we'd expect it to hold the number of times `value` appears (without the plus one).

That said, the algorithm still returns the correct answer: it does indeed return a mode, as claimed.  For example, with your example input, it correctly returns `2`.

(Why?  Because the exact value of `modecount` isn't returned.  It's one too high for every value, so the mode will indeed have the largest value of `modecount`.)

So while the pseudocode is confusing and poorly constructed, it happens to return the right answer -- i.e., it happens to be a correct algorithm for the "find a mode" problem.  But it's still ugly.  Yuck.  I agree with you that they should have initialized the count to 0, not 1; then the algorithm would be both correct *and* easier to understand.